# Доступ к сайту по двум доменам, на одном из которых редирект

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Подскажите, возможно ли такое: чтобы сайт открывался с двух разных доменов, при этом нужно, чтобы только один из доменов редиректил на другой сайт. Сейчас сайт сидит на одном домене и редиректит на другой:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://other-site.ru [L,R=301]
```

Мне же нужно временно открыть доступ к сайту с другого домена без редиректа.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^show-this-site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redirect-this-site.ru
RewriteRule (.*) https://new-site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```